# ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript with return value

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am running a ASP.NET page inside a C# WebBrowser. The ASP.NET page needs to fetch a varible by making a window.external call, which works perfectly. 
The issue I'm having is storing this value which is currently getting fetched like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page,this.GetType(),"FetchData","window.external.FetchData()",true);
```

If I alert out this value, it verifies that the value is fetched. However I cannot seem to find a way to store this value. I need it stored for code-behind. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use AJAX.

Comment: I don´t know what kind of data you are receiving, but you could put it into a asp:hiddenfield. You can read the hiddenfield from server side afterwards.

Comment: I'm just receiving a string, and I was hoping not to do any changes to the aspx page or the master page (it needs to be implemented on several pages, so creating a class library is the best way to go).